# Vimperator: How to list the history in current tab and select one to go back to?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, vimperator

Vimperator has the key "H" to page back, but how can I view a list of history for the current tab and go back to a selected one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The `jumps` command

You can use the `:jumps` command (or just `:ju`). This brings up a numbered "jump list" with the tab's history. You can then navigate to the urls using hints or the mouse.

---

#### If hint keys <kbd>f</kbd> and <kbd>F</kbd> aren't working

When I just tested this on the version of Vimperator on my laptop, normal hints using <kbd>f</kbd> or <kbd>F</kbd> weren't working for some reason. I'm sure they should (and they do on Pentadactyl), so hopefully they'll work for you. If they don't, you can always use the <kbd>;</kbd> family of extended hint bindings instead:

- <kbd>;</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> open hint in current tab
- <kbd>;</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> open hint in new tab
- <kbd>;</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> open hint in new background tab
- <kbd>;</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> open hint in new window

and so forth...

You can also use the numbers as arguments to <kbd>Ctrl-o</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-i</kbd>. So if you want to jump to #3 on the jump list, you can just type <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-o</kbd>.

---

#### Creating a key binding

If you want a key binding for the jump list, you can define one by adding the following line to your `$HOME/.vimperatorrc` file:

```
map <C-j> :jumps<CR>
```

This defines <kbd>Ctrl-j</kbd> as a shortcut for the jump list. It only works in normal/visual mode, ie. not while you're in a text area, have a menu open, etc.

Comment: `:jumps` not working for my Firefox. Nothing pops up, no reaction, seemingly Vimperator ignores the command.

Comment: @Chinggis6 Yeah, it seems to be broken ATM. Probably by the latest changes in FF. It still works on the old version on my Windows laptop (vimperator 3.9, FF 31), but when I test it on my desktop FF ESR (vimperator 3.15, FF 45), I get a "TypeError: is not iterable" error. It's still working in Pentadactyl, though.